# How to figure out why package is not hoisted in yarn3 monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, monorepo, hoisting, yarn-workspaces

I'm using `yarn 3` monorepo and for some reason, `react-dom` package is not hoisted properly:
The same version of `react-dom` is duplicated across packanges.

```
qnm react-dom
react-dom 18.1.0 ↰ 18 hours ago
├── 16.14.0 ⇡ 1 year ago
└─┬ package-a
  └── 16.14.0 ⇡ 1 year ago
```

I have the next resolutions in root package.json

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    ...
  }
```

I read that package could be prevented from hoisting because of wrong peer dependencies,
but seems that everything is a correct and hoisted version of `react` is meeting the peer dependency requirement of `react-dom`:

```
npm info react-dom@16.14.0 peerDependencies
{ react: '^16.14.0' }
```

Also, I've trying to do `yarn dedupe` and it's not helping.

Can you suggest any tool or approach how to debug why a package is not hoisted, with `yarn 3`?

Comment: Yes, usually, if a package were not hoisted - means there were at least two sets of peer dependencies with different resolved versions. In the case you describe, it is unlikely the case. Your question lacks minimal and complete reproduction, which makes it very hard to answer, the guesses might be very different here. Repro is needed

Comment: I know that would be great to provide a reproduction of the issue, but it's hard in my case but I'll give it a shot.  
Meanwhile, I'm seeking a way how to debug this issue on my own. 
Or at least Ideas why this is happnening.

Comment: Well, one hint for you is to use `NM_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 yarn` and check the output. It will contain reasons why the packages were not hoisted, and in case that won't work with your Yarn version, try to upgrade / downgrade Yarn version you use.

Comment: We aligned versions `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` and `react-dom` is hoisted.
Seems that this is the issue of `yarn@3`. I think that `@types/react` should not affect the hosting of `react-dom` since it's not a peer dependency.

Comment: Yes, this is an issue starting from Yarn 2+. Auto adding of `@types/` peer dependencies is done by Yarn core to help with `pnp` compatibility. While I personally would like this auto-adding to be removed to not interfere with `node_modules` hoisting, but its quite an effort, someone need to step in and dedicate plenty of time to contribute this.